# SQL query to get fields from 2nd table based on input from 1st

Tags: sql

I have 2 tables, table1 and table2

table1 -

| sn | timestamp |
| --- | --- |
| 123 | 123456 |

table2 -

| sn | timestamp | code |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 456 | 123456 | xxxxx |

I want to first get the sn from table1 with max timestamp(epoch) and then query table 2 with the sn returned from table1 and get the code from table2 with the max timestamp.

I am trying this but getting errors -

`select code from table2 where sn = (select sn, max(timestamp) from table1 GROUP BY sn)`

Should i use joins instead?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select DISTINCT code from table2 
where sn = (select sn from table1 WHERE timestamp = (SELECT MAX(timestamp) FROM Table1));
```

Comment: The second part of the query `SELECT MAX(timestamp) FROM Table1` will return the max ts but not for the each individual `sn` i think. or am i seeing this wrong?

Comment: @Dan The goal there is to find 'sn' value having maximum timestamp value. We don't need any GROUP BY there.

Comment: ok. but i get back a lot of duplicates actually, seems like i need to filter by max timestamp for the code returned.

Comment: Then put the DISTINCT keyword before the first select statement. I am updating my code. Please test it.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using the following code:

```
SELECT code
from table2 t
where sn = (SELECT sn
            FROM table1 t1
            INNER JOIN (SELECT MAX(timestamp) AS max_ts
                        FROM table1) d
              ON t1.timestamp = d.max_ts
           )
INNER JOIN (SELECT MAX(timestamp) AS max_ts
           FROM table2) t2
  ON t.timestamp= t2.max_ts;
```

However using the example tables you provided this will return no results, as the sn 123 isn't found in table2

Comment: This will not give the `code` with the latest timestamp right? i mean since i have multiple sn in table2 as well

Comment: and what is the `d` after the inner join statement?

Comment: the d is giving the query an alias (some databases require it and since you didn't specify what db you are using you may need it). I would suggest you update your post with a better explanation and more sample of data, as from your initial question its not clear you wish to perform the query with multiple sns. If you update your post I can provide a better solution but you'd need to use windows functions from the sound of it

Comment: Ah unless you mean the sn can exist multiple times in table2 and you want to filter that to just the latest timestamp? If so you would just need to perform an inner join again to get the maxt_ts from table2. I can update the code to demonstrate this

Answer (score 0):

To get the "latest" value I always use windowing functions.

In order to keep everything clean, I've used two CTEs to define the two datasets but you can put everything in a single query if needed.

```
WITH latestDataT1 AS (
SELECT 
     sn
    ,timestamp
FROM (
    SELECT
        sn
        ,timestamp
        ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY timestamp DESC) as RowNo
    FROM table1
)
WHERE
    RowNo = 1
)
WITH latestDataT2 AS (
SELECT
     sn
    ,timestamp
    ,code
FROM (
    SELECT 
         sn
        ,timestamp
        ,code
        ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION sn BY ORDER BY timestamp DESC) as RowNo
    FROM table2
)
WHERE
    RowNo = 1
)

SELECT
    *
FROM latestDataT1 AS t1
LEFT JOIN latestDataT2 AS t2
    ON t1.sn = t2.sn
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try one of these scripts:

1)
select code
from table2
where (sn, timestamp) in (select sn, max(timestamp) from table1 GROUP BY sn);

2)

```
select A.code, B.maxtime 
  from table2 A,  
       (select sn, max(timestamp) as maxtime 
          from table1 GROUP BY sn) B
 where A.sn        = B.sn
   and A.timestamp = B.maxtime;
```

Thank you